# Where can I read about conditionals done with "?" and ":" (colon)?

Tags: php, syntax, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I've been doing conditionals with if/else or a year or so now. Looking at some new code, I'm seeing a conditional that appears to use `?` and `:` instead of if and else. I'd like to learn more about this, but I am not sure what to google to find articles explaining how it works. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Basic usage is something like

```
$foo = (if this expressions returns true) ? (assign this value to $foo) : (otherwise, assign this value to $foo)
```

It can be used for more than assignment though, it looks like other examples are cropping up below.

I think the reason you see this in a lot of modern, OO style PHP is that without static typing you end up needing to be paranoid about the types in any particular variable, and a one line ternary is less cluttered than a 7 line if/else conditional.

Also, in deference to the comments and truth in naming, read all about [<s>the</s> ternary operator**s**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) in computer science.

Comment: It’s *a* ternary operator and not *the* ternary operator.

Comment: @Gumbo - I thought the same thing. Unfortunately the PHP documentation has it backwards. It says one of the conditional operators is the ternary operator. One more reason I don't like PHP...:-P

Comment: In the context of PHP it's THE ternary operator, as enshrined in the manual page.  Take it up with them.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: I know it’s often referred to as “the” ternary operator as it’s the only ternary operator in PHP I know of. But what else conditional operators are there that it’s only referred to as being one of them?

Comment: @Gumbo - I have no idea. Like I said, I think their documentation is backwards too (hence my answer).

Comment: Wikipedia link added to clear up pesky things like "truth in naming"

Answer (score 3):

That would be the conditional operator. It's pretty much a single line if/then/else statement:

```
if(someCondition){
    $x = doSomething();
}
else{
    $x = doSomethingElse();
}
```

Becomes:

```
$x = someCondition ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: *The* conditional operator. Isn't there more than one?

Answer (score 1):

It is:

> condition ? do_if_true : do_if_false

So, for example in the below, do->something() will be run.

```
$true = 1;
$false = 0

$true ? $do->something() : $do->nothing();
```

But in the below example, do->nothing() will be run.

```
$false ? $do->something() : $do->nothing();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is *the* ternary operator in PHP. It's shorthand for if/else, format is:

```
condition ? true expression : false expression;
```

Comment: It’s *a* ternary operator and not *the* ternary operator.

Comment: Yes. *Ternary operator* just means that there are three operands like a binary has two operands (e.g. `a+b`, `a&b`, `a/b`, etc.) and a unary has just one operand (e.g. `!a`, `~a`, `@a`, etc.). But since PHP has just one ternary operator, it’s often referred to as the ternary operation.

Comment: @Gumbo. Thanks for the deep insight. I wasn't sure if you were serious. As a moderator of this community I didn't expect you to begrudge an active participant such things. I've seen a lot of that this week. I guess it's understandable as syntax is our life. However, I hope that doesn't become a trend of this community.

Comment: I just like to use a proper terminology. But it might be pedantic in this case.