# Undefined index (PHP)

Tags: php, indexing

Need some explanation.
I made form as following:

```
<form action="test4.php" method="post">
    <select name="code">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
        <option value="E">E</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Cus!">
</form>
```

Then to store value of the form to $code, I used a line of script that I found in a forum

```
$code= empty ($_POST['code']) ? null : $_POST['code'];
```

Actually It worked, But it was not explained.
Anybody can explain it to me??

Comment: Search "Ternary operator" its a shorthand way of writing an if/else conditional check.

Comment: See [`empty()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [ternary operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: What does this have to do with "Undefined index"?

Comment: If you're asking what a ternary statement is then its a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681832/what-does-sign-in-this-statement/4681862. If you're asking about undefined indexes it's too localized.

Comment: I didnt even know that was Ternary statement.
I got unidentified index error, searched for some solution then I found that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). The syntax is `var = (true) ? trueValue : falseValue;` It's the same as this:

```
if  ( empty($_POST['code']) ) {
    $code =  null;
} else {
    $code = $_POST['code'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) returns `true` if the variable is `0`, `false`, `null`, empty string, not defined etc.

`(condition ? result-if-condition-is-true : result-if-condition-is-false)` is called a `ternary operator` and [can be found here in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

It could also be written as this:

```
if (empty($_POST["code"])) {
    $code = null;
} else {
    $code = $_POST["code"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a ternary operator.

Ternary operators take the following form:

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

The line in your example is equivalent to the following:

```
if (empty($_POST["code"])) {
    $code = null;
}
else {
    $code = $_POST["code"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rad, its a ternary expression. it simply means check the content of $_POST['code'], if true set null else set the value $_POST['code'] to $code .

Rad if you have got your answer, pls tick the check mark against the answer,this would reduce the number of open questions and will be removed from open questions pool.