# need an explanation of return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1 in php

Tags: php, return

A bit of a silly question for more advanced programmers, but In my quest to learn php I have come across return statements that involve a ? symbol with values of 0, -1 and 1 such as:

```
return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
```

or

```
[$index ? 0 : 1];
```

Im trying to understand the logic of what this statement does and why it is used, any help will go a long way, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php); See as well: [Where can I read about conditionals done with ? and :](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055355/where-can-i-read-about-conditionals-done-with-and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;`

If `$a` is greater than `$b` return `-1`, else return `1`.

It is the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (a.k.a shorthand if/else statement)

Comment: what does -1 symbolize exactly? does it mean for example true or false?

Comment: They both evaluate to boolean `true`. However, the returned value will be the number, not a boolean.

Comment: @edmund in boolean true is denoted by 1 and false is denoted by 0, -1 does not serves no meaning for a boolean. if you want to create a boolean then it should be `return ($a > $b) ? 0 : 1;` or best could be `return ($a > $b) ? true : false;` or simply put use  `return ($a > $b)`

Comment: interesting! what about 0? I have seen this here and there as well, what would that equate to?

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar - or directly `return ($a > $b)` :)

Comment: @shef that is not correct, `-1` will evaluate to boolean true not false, check this `var_dump((bool) -1);`

Comment: @edmund: As Ibrahim has explained, `0` will evaluate to boolean `false`.

Comment: @edmund: Between the comparison you are making, only 0 evaluates to boolean `false`, not both.

Comment: @edmund please take a minute to read the answer properly, i have already told 0 is equal to false and 1 is equal to true, apart from integer 0 rest all evaluates to true in boolean. consider boolean like a switch with only two controls `ON` and `OFF`, `ON = 1` & `OFF = 0` as simple as that.

Comment: interesting, just throws me off when i saw some people use a 0, appreciate the help though guys!

Comment: @edmund: The first statement seems to be part of a comparison function (a function you can pass e.g. to `usort`). Such a function has to return `0` if both arguments are equal, `-1` if the first argument is smaller than the second and `1` if it is bigger.

Comment: ah yes! I think this would explain why! so the -1 is used in cases where there is a possibility for a true, false and an equal?

Answer (score 2):

`?` is the ternary operator. If the boolean expression `($a > $b)` is true then `-1` is returned else `1` is returned. It is just a short `if else` combination.

To summarise `boolean expression ? x : y` is equal to:

```
if (boolean expression)
   evaluates to x
else
   evaluates to y
```

Comment: so basically -1 is equal to $a and 1 = $b?

Comment: @edmund - No. If the `boolean` expression `($a > $b)` is `true`, then the result of the ternary operator is `-1` else it is `1`. Look at the summarization in my post.

Answer (score 2):

It's same like

```
if ($a > $b) 
      return -1; 
else

      return 1;
```

(It's shorthand)

Search for "ternary" on **[this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)** page

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it similar to C's if statement but in one line? So I thought this is the PHP equivalent:

```
if ($a > $b) {
return -1;
} else {
return 1;
}
```

Whilst the short hand version would be:

```
return (($a > $b) ? -1 : 1);
```

So what you're having is something like this:

```
(if true) ? then : else;
```

Check out [this](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) for more details.