# checking for null and assigning in php

Tags: php, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I read about conditionals done with ? and :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055355/where-can-i-read-about-conditionals-done-with-and)

I want do the following without using if else or a ternary operator:

if `$_GET['a']` is not null then set `$a= $_GET['a']` else set its value to `"default"`.

I tried `$a= $_GET['a'] || "default"`. but it doesnt work.
I remember seeing something like this in a code sample, but I can't recall now.

Comment: A simple Google search will give u http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: He said he didn't want a ternary operator

Comment: Then just use an *if* or actually understand the operators. They are documented. `(NULL !== $a = $_GET['a']) || $a = "default";`. This is trivial material.

Comment: Although I am not too sure I understand what the OP is trying to achieve, I'm pretty sure he DIDN'T ask "how to determine if a variable contains null" and cleraly stated that he DIDN't want to use the ternary operator...

Comment: Starting with PHP 5.3, a shorter version of the ternary operator is available, so you could write: `$a= @$_GET['a'] ?: "default";` - which is almost equivalent to `a = something || 'default';` in javascript (except that it may raise an E_NOTICE error, therefore i added an `@`).

Starting with PHP7 you can use the fully equivalent null coalesce operator: `$a= $_GET['a'] ?? "default";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a ternary if *is* your best bet here.

In this case I would use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) check - to determine if the key is set and is not null:

```
$a = isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : "default"
```

The or operator `||` doesn't work to null coalesce like that in PHP, but you might have seen it in JavaScript where it can be used to set a value to the first non-false result:

e.g

```
var a = get['a'] || 'default';
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this PHP shorthand if/else (ternary) information in http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

and also

http://davidwalsh.name/learning-ternary-operators-tips-tricks

Comment: Not just link. They disappear over time. Add the code-examples. Otherwise just leave a comment with the links.

Answer (score 0):

Well, people here doesn't seem to bother reading the entire question this late.

That sintax you wrote works on some other languages but apparently not on php. I think you should just stick to the ternary operator or write a function for that as a shortcut if you're going to use this kind of verification a lot on your page.

```
function GET($v, $default)
{
    return !isset($_GET[$v]) || empty($_GET[$v]) ? $default : $_GET[$v];
}

$a = GET("a", "default");
```